# Parameterized Multi-Row Insert into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm facing a situation where I need to insert as many as 17,000 rows into a SQL Server database all at once.  I've come up with two ways to do that, but I'm getting tripped up over query parameterization in C#.

One caveat: I'm worried about performance, but not to the exclusion of all else -- if the operation I'm doing takes 8 minutes, then whether I add another 5 seconds vs. 10 seconds for the data insert doesn't really matter.  If the data insert takes an additional 10 minutes on top of the initial operation, that's a big deal.

**Option 1: Multi-Row Insert (chunked)**

The first option is to do a simple multi-row insert:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, LastName, Age)
   VALUES
      ('Bob', 'Smith', 24),
      ('Sally', 'Jones', 32),
      ('Jennifer', 'Johnson', 23)
```

I would build up several of these queries via something like this. (I'm writing this off of the top of my head, so there's almost certainly a bug in here. That's not important -- it's meant to illustrate my point):

```
var queriesNeeded = people.Count / 250;

for (int i = 0; i < queriesNeeded; i++)
{
   var records = people.Skip(i * 250).Take(250);
   BuildAndExecuteQuery(records);
}

// Handle anything left over
var leftoverRecords = people.Skip(queriesNeeded * 250);
BuildAndExecuteQuery(leftoverRecords);
```

However, while I know how to paramaterize a basic single-line INSERT, I don't know how to go about paramaterizing an `INSERT` that can have an unknown number of variables in it.  Is there a way to do that?  How would I go about creating my `SqlCommand` for this?

**Option 2: SqlBulkCopy Class**

Or... I could go the [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) route.  The only problem I have here is that I can't find anything that indicates how to parameterize this, or if I even need to.  Do I need to worry about escaping my data, or handling parameters at all here?

Comment: Is records a table in the database or some other input?

Comment: Use a table valued parameter and this is super simple. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine

Comment: or SqlBulkCopy with a DataTable which means you don't have to worry about escaping anything.

Comment: Yeah. Bulk Copy or a table parameter are the two primary options. You can pass your DataTable either way you go.

Comment: @SeanLange The only problem with a table-valued parameter is that I have limited access to altering the DB (adding sprocs or whatnot), so it would be better if I could do this entirely within C#.  The table itself is usually managed by Entity Framework; this is just a special case where I have to insert a lot of data into it.

Comment: And SQL query in c# is a string.  Adding parameters specify to column types so the low level driver doesn't have to guess the type.  Error can occur just like in Excel when a cell is specified in GENERAL format and spreadsheet often changes type to wrong type.  Bulk copy you do not have to have parameters because the type is already in the column and the database.  You will get an error with Bulkcopy if the source and destination tables do not have the same types in the columns.

Comment: @jdweng So from that description, since there's no string, there's no opportunity for SQL injection either, right?

Comment: SQL injection involves credentials.  So if you have a secure connection injection shouldn't occur.  The is why I recommend using a Windows credential for SQL connections which require the client and server to be in the same windows group and have the user have accounts on both client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Not much experience with in-memory Bulk Copy here, but I can certainly answer this:

> I don't know how to go about paramaterizing an INSERT that can have
>   an unknown number of variables in it.

You do it by adding parameters in the same loop that you use to add them to the query.

To extend your psuedo-code, you would replace this:

```
   BuildAndExecuteQuery(records);
```

With something like this:

```
foreach record in records
{
   Add parameter(s) to the query
   Add the same parameter(s) to the command's Parameters collection
}
ExecuteQuery
```